# ASP.NET on mono: System.TypeLoadException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ubuntu, mono

I would like to develop a website with ASP and run it on a Ubuntu or Debian server using Mono. To start I have created a very simple application with Visual Studio on Windows and want to deploy it to a Ubuntu box, just to see that it works. But so far it doesn't.

What I have done: I have created an ASP.NET (version 2) application with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows. Then I have published the project to my file system an copied it to the server. It runs Mono version 3.2.8. I have configured a vhost following this instruction: http://devblog.rayonnant.net/2012/11/mvc3-working-in-mono-ubuntu-1210.html.

However, if I open the browser and try to open the website, I get a `System.TypeLoadException`. It says:

```
Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): <myprojectname>
```

Needless to say that this error does not occur in the debug environment.

I have been trying to fight this all day but I can't figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is ASP.NET (version 2)? Why do you use MVC 4 tag? If yourself cannot explain the details clear enough, no one can help much.